# Embedding data in a F# (micro) service

Tags: .net, dataframe, f#, embedded-resource, suave

I am trying to create a F# + Suave based micro service, that takes a request and uses a few matrices and lookup tables to calculate a response. The service *has to* run on in a docker container on Linux (mono later CoreCLR).

These matrices and lookup tables have from 1000 up to 1 million elements (usually floats) and are generated offline with various IPython notebooks (Pandas DataFrames).

Is it possible to embed these matrices in a binary format in the service and if so, what would be the best practice(s) to do that?

So far I looked into resgen but which seems to be focused mostly on localisation problems. I am also thinking about exporting the Pandas DataFrame into a CSV and then create a script to convert these into binary data. But how would I embed these binaries in my F#/Suave service? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Have you looked at including them as an embedded resource?

Comment: if with this you mean resgen, then yes I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can just deploy the binaries next to the application and load and parse 
them at start up time.

The compiler can also embed the binaries inside the product .dll or .exe file although I do not see much advantage to it.

Comment: it would make deployment easier, less brittle and assuming that my binaries are valid IL(?) incompatible changes in my data would result in compile time errors and not runtime crashes